# Is there a way to call Azure Devops via python using 'requests'?

Tags: python, azure

So, from what I see from most [sources](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api), they say if youre trying to make a python program call azure devops api calls, it uses a python import statement such as :

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
...
```

Is there any way to use requests or other built in import statements so I dont have to install these devops specific modules? I'm coding in putty so I dont have a way to install these modules.

If anyone's got any solutions or ideas I'd be happy to hear it!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Surely, it is supported to use `requests` to call [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Firstly, you need to create a [personal access token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

Then you can use the PAT to create the basic auth header, and make the request:

```
import requests
import base64

pat = 'tcd******************************tnq'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}

response = requests.get(
    url="https://dev.azure.com/jack0503/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1", headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm sure that was a surface level question but it helps wrap my head around things. Do you know if theres anything else I would need to do different regarding the API in terms of searching for PBIs and searching for terms in the titles, or should that be fairly straightforward?

Comment: Do you refer to Power BI? Actually, Microsoft officially provides documentation for [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/). While the the authentication problem issolved, calling the API is very simple.

Comment: Is the PAT mandatory? Can I use login and password?

Comment: @AstraSerg for basic authentication with login and password you can use `requests.get(url="http://dev.azure...", auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, p))`. There's a fine example here https://www.clouddev.engineering/azure-devops-rest-api-with-python/